# Python disable some keys of keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, disabled-input

I want a python script that can disable the keyboard. I mean no matter which key I press no program or even operating system should detect those keys strokes.

And in some cases I don't want the whole keyboard to be disable but some keys. Like `Function keys`, `Ctrl`, `shift`, `tab` etc.

Is there a way of doing that? Or is there some python library?